# If $A$ is a compact operator, is $\overline{A(B_1(0))}$ finite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be an operator. An operator is called compact iff $\overline{A(B_1(0))}$ is compact.

A normed space is finite iff $\overline{B_1(0)}$ is compact.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a Hilbert space and consider the operator $A:X\rightarrow Y$. Let $A$ be compact, i.e. $\overline{A(B_1(0))}$ is compact.

Can you say the following: $\overline{A(B_1(0))}$ is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because not every set is/contains a ball, e.g. the Hilbert cube.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know the cube so I've just read wikipedia. What about X and Y? What are you taking?

Comment: How about $X = \ell^\infty$, $Y = \ell^2$?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but wasn't sure. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A good example to think about this is to take $X=Y=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and 
$$
Ax=(x_1,\frac{x_2}2,\frac{x_3}3,\ldots)
$$
Then $A$ is compact (it is a norm limit of finite-rank). The image of $A$ is dense, because it contains all the elements of the canonical orthonormal basis. And
$$
\overline{A(B(0,1))}=\overline{\{x\in\ell^2(\mathbb N):\ \sum_n n^2|x_n|^2<\infty\}}.
$$